# Реализация двух разных функционалов на одном диалоговом окне QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

я разрабатываю приложение на QT c++. Задача приложение заключается в том что берутся все изображения из выбранной папки, по очереди выводятся на экран, а пользователь выделяет область и обрезанная картинка помещается в выбранную папку. С этим проблем нет. Но потребовалось реализовать ещё один функционал приложения. Программа должна также брать все картинки из папки , по очереди выводить на экран , а пользователь выделяет объект в изображении точками и создаётся маска изображения и она также сохраняется. Суть вопроса : как лучше (или правильней ) сделать. Создать ещё одно диалоговое окно и в нём сделать функционал по созданию маски , или сделать тумблер с выбором "обрезка" или "маска" и реализовывать их в одном диалоговом окне. Если в одном окне то подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это реализовать .
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В чем проблема? В общих словах: одно окно, одна сцена, только разные способы ввода координат (разные курсоры) - резиновый прямоугольник и точечный ввод. Можно по этим точкам еще сплайн или полигон рисовать на сцене.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать . Я сам студент, QT нам не преподавали, а курсовая у меня сделать приложение на QT.

Comment: Так же я не совсем понимаю как лучше мне реализовать меню настроек приложения. Дело в том что мне надо так же картинки группировать , как именно группировать должен выбрать пользователь (группировка по имени, группировать по директориям или в отдельном файле ). Я создал отдельное окно настроек, там добавил Radio button, а что дальше делать пока не знаю .